# Typeform and Calendly redirection in the same iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently, when a user completes an embedded Typeform on my website, the user is redirected to an external Calendly link.

I'm looking for a Typeform and Calendly integration in the same iframe, which means the user will stay on my website when he clicks the button at the end of the Typeform instead of being redirected to an external Calendly link.

Here's what the Typeform embed code looks like (I've made the URL generic) :

(function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })()

Here's what the Calendly redirection code, as well as the embed code, looks like (I've made the URL generic):

Redirection code:

https://calendly.com/myaccount/my-calendly-event

Embed code:

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The embed code weren't copied correctly. Here they are again:

Comment: <div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://suddomain.typeform.com/to/ABCDEF" data-button-text="COMMENCER" style="”width:100%;height:500px;”"></div> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>

Comment: <!-- Début de widget en ligne Calendly -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/myaccount/my-calendly-event" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Fin de widget en ligne Calendly -->

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a native feature offered by Typeform. It's called "redirect after submitting".

Once the user has filled your form they will be redirected to the URL of your choice, in this case Calendly.

You chan check [Typeform Help Center](https://www.typeform.com/help/redirect-after-submitting/) for all the details.

It's something you can turn on on the settings of your Form by clicking on the gear icon. There you setup the URL and decide to pass variables to it, or not.

Hope it's clear :)